# Get list of numbers from SQL server and use it to get unique values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to do the following:

1. I have a pandas dataframe 'df' with 20 columns. 'ISBN-13' is one of them.
2. Our SQL server database 'Book_records' has a table with 'Isbn13' column containing the IDs similar to 'ISBN-13' in the pandas dataframe.

My goal is to get the records(rows) from the pandas dataframe which are not present in our SQL server database

I tried doing this:

Get a list of 'Isbn13' numbers from my SQL database into pandas using the following.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host=server, database=db1,trusted_connection=tcon)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT distinct(DBF.Isbn13) FROM Book_records as DBF")
isbn13_list = cursor.fetchall()
```

Then using this list, compare it with the pandas dataframe ISBN-13 values eliminate those that are already present in our database.
However, when I run this. I am getting, what I think is a list of list as follows

```
isbn13_list[1:4]
[(u'9780004707631', ), (u'9780004812595', ), (u'9780006485131', )]
```

My pandas dataframe column is as follows: `Name: ISBN-13, Length: 821, dtype: float64` and will have elements like `9780004707631.0`

When I run the following program to get the new values not present it our database, I get all the values which is wrong (I checked I should get 200 less values)

```
Final_df = df[~df['ISBN-13'].isin(isbn13_list)]
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, should I convert ISBN-13 in my df to int or anything else?

Comment: check your data type , make all str or all int

Comment: is the isbn13_list coming out correctly for it to work for the Final_df code?
Also, it takes a ton of time to run. is it because of the way isbn13_list is?

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting, what I think is a list of list

No. `fetchall()` returns a list of `pyodbc.Row` objects. If you want a true list of `float` values to filter your dataframe then you need to convert the list of `Row` objects to a list of `float` values like so:

```python
isbn13_rows = cursor.fetchall()  # [(u'9780004707631', ), (u'9780004812595', ), ...
isbn13_list = [float(x[0]) for x in isbn13_rows]  # [9780004707631.0, 9780004812595.0, ...
```

(BTW, it would probably be better if your dataframe stored the ISBNs as strings instead of float values.)

Answer (score 0):

This was a workaround I was able to do. It was quite quick that what all I previously tried. It might not be optimal so sorry for that.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}', host=server, database=db1,trusted_connection=tcon)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT distinct(DBF.Isbn13) FROM Book_records as DBF")
isbn13_list = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(),columns=['isbn13'])
isbn13_list = isbn13_list['isbn13'].astype('int64')
Final_df = condition_df[~condition_df['ISBN-13'].isin(isbn13_list)]
```